# Find number character in a string and print them

Tags: java, string

I have a string as "abbcccdddd" then I want a program so that I can get the number of characters present in the string and it should be output as "ab2c3d4"
Hope to get ans in an easy way and in efficient way .
Sample input
abbaaaccc

Sample Output
ab2a3c3

Comment: If what you want is help, no problem. If what you want is a program, then hire a developer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework dump without any research effort.

Comment: Thanks for ur effort..

Answer (score 0):

here is a java function for your problem:

```
public static String rleEncode(String toEncode) {
StringBuffer dest = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < toEncode.length(); i++) {
    int runLength = 1;
    while (i+1 < toEncode.length() && toEncode.charAt(i) == toEncode.charAt(i+1)) {
        runLength++;
        i++;
    }
    dest.append(runLength);
    dest.append(toEncode.charAt(i));
}
return dest.toString();
```

}

Just put your String as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

This will give exact what you expect.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="abbaaaccc";
    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        int charCount=1;
        while(i+1<s.length() && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i+1)) {
            charCount++;
            i++;
        }
        result.append(s.charAt(i));
        if(charCount>1) {
        result.append(charCount);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);

    }
```